# Error when making a POST request with Confluent parallel-consumer and vertx

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x

I need to create a POST request with vertx, following the example "parallel-consumer-example-vertx" I created a "webClient" to later invoke "parallelConsumer.vertxHttpRequestStream". But at the moment of sending a Json as body, the flow of the application breaks; because the POST request is done infinitely because the commit to the kafka queue record is not done.

Code fragment in method "run()":

```
this.parallelConsumer = JStreamVertxParallelStreamProcessor.createEosStreamProcessor(options);
parallelConsumer.subscribe(of(inputTopic));

Stream resultStream = parallelConsumer.vertxHttpRequestStream((webClient, rec) -> {
            
            System.out.println("Msg recibido");
            
            ConsumerRecord consumerRecord = rec.getSingleConsumerRecord();
            
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();

            JsonObject payload = new JsonObject(consumerRecord.value().toString());
            System.out.println("Payload" + payload);
            
            RequestInfo reqInf = new RequestInfo("localhost", port, "/send-message", params);

            HttpRequest<Buffer> req = (HttpRequest<Buffer>) webClient.post(reqInf.getPort(), reqInf.getHost(), reqInf.getContextPath());
                   /* Error */
                   /* 
                    .sendJsonObject(new JsonObject("{\"hola\":\"mundo\"}"));
                    .onSuccess(res -> {
                        System.out.println(res.bodyAsString());
                    });
                   */

            return req;
});
```

I was expecting the application to commit to kafka's record, just like it does when sending a webClient without body.

Thank you for your help

Documentation: https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Example: https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer/blob/master/parallel-consumer-examples/parallel-consumer-example-vertx/src/main/java/io/confluent/parallelconsumer/examples/vertx/VertxApp.java